# Vertical alignment of svg inside button in Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to center the "x" in the red circular button using Tailwind CSS.  I've tried numerous css but nothing worked.  What will fix it?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/Wz54NCHCI8

[image: misaligned x in button]

```
<button type="button" class="flex justify-center select-none bg-red-500 border-2 text-white
      text-xl font-bold p-2 m-2 rounded-full shadow h-20 w-20 focus:outline-none
      focus:shadow-outline"><img src="/icons/x.svg" alt="" width="40" h="40" class="icon svelte-1iu276v"></button>
```

Comment: Documentation  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/vertical-align

Comment: That doesn't work.  I have read the documentation.  Is it on the correct element?

Comment: [Is that what you want?](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yrUz7tWneA)

Comment: Yes.  What did you change?  Added items-center?

Comment: @ROMS Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding [`items-center`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) will center your icon vertically and [`justify-center`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content) will center your icon horizontally.

Code:

```html
<button type="button" class="flex justify-center items-center select-none bg-red-500 border-2 text-white text-xl font-bold p-2 m-2 rounded-full shadow h-20 w-20 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x">
        <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
        <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
    </svg>
</button>
```

Result:

[image: Preview]

[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/iuVkBYdEio)